# Why ( ) instead of { } with arrow function callbacks inside of map() in JSX? (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The code in my callback function in the map below was originally encapsulated in curly brackets, but it didn't work. It took me forever to identify the issue. This is just one of several syntactical issues I've run across with learning React. Just wondering why this is?

```
const Stuff = () => {
return (
    <ul>
        {
            things.map((item, i) => (
                <li key={i}>{item}</li>
            ))
        }
    </ul>
)
```

}

Answer (score 1):

It's important to know that with arrow functions, if the function is only one line long, and is not surrounded with braces, the function will return whatever follows the arrow.

Essentially, by using `()` you are saving yourself from having to use the return keyword. I like to think of `()` as a way to style the code so that it is easily readable.

Comment: That's good to know, except I am wondering why it is () instead of {}. In vanilla JS, I might do something like () => {console.log('something')}

Comment: @narojo Even in Vanilla JS you do not need to use `{}` on one line functions. The `()` are used so that you can use more than one line of code without having to use the `return` keyword. It's basically used for readability in your code. [This article explains it well](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/curly-braces-versus-parenthesis-in-reactjs-4d3ffd33128f). The use of `()` is from Vanilla JS.